# Implementing a help system

Tags: android, standards, help-system

**Questions**: is there any *default* way of presenting a help feature in Android? AFAIK, no. So, it follows: is there such a library or component to help (or trying to) standardize this? There is also that green tutorial when you first turn on the device. How's that done? Is it reusable?

**Question context if you care**: I developed my own help system to use in Android apps: the usual frontpage -> topics, using reusable `Fragment`s and layouts. It performs "well enough" for my needs, but it grew from ad hoc needs, and it's starting to become a burden (requiring rework, and I already see a need to start from scratch with proper abstraction this time). I see mobile apps are *almost* always simple enough to not require help at all, or almost no help. Contextual help is also being implemented very well in those cases lately, for what I can see. However, there are apps that, for the natural complexity of the subject, requires a traditional help system (my case). And that's where my question comes from.

Please take a moment to see that this is *not* an argumentative question, although it certainly has room for such a discussion (in case answer is "no" to both).

Thank you for your time.

ps.: Google is of no use, of course, since "help" as in "help platform" is ambiguous with "help" as in "I need help for (whatever)". I tried and gave up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any default way of presenting a help feature in Android?

Not at this time.

> So, it follows: is there such a library or component to help (or trying to) standardize this?

Not that I am aware of, beyond simply linking to a Web page, YouTube video, etc. I've long campaigned for somebody to write something, probably based on `WebView`. And, if nobody beats me to it, I might do it in the next 6-12 months.

> There is also that green tutorial when you first turn on the device. How's that done?

Using widgets, presumably. `Button`, `TextView`, etc.

> Is it reusable?

I don't think the setup wizard is part of the Android open source project.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. Thank you.

Comment: Very interesting - would also be interested in a reusable component for this functionality

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, more than a year has passed since your answer, have you started the help library?

Comment: If I ever do mine, I'll release it and comment here. But I'm moving more and more stuff into contextual help lately, so this is not a high priority project.

Comment: @Jose_GD: Sorry, as with David, other things took priority.